# Why doesn't my input value end up in tax_query terms after I submit form with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I would like to change my tax_query terms after I submit form with ajax. Ajax form is submitting every time I click on li element. For some reason the data doesn't end up in terms.

Form setup

```
  <?php

        $taxonomy = 'blog_categories';
        $terms = get_terms($taxonomy); // Get all terms of a taxonomy

        if ($terms && !is_wp_error($terms)) :
        ?>
      <form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="tax-filter">
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach ($terms as $term) { ?>
                        <li class="blog-selection"><?= $term->name; ?></li>
                                <input type="hidden" name="term" value="<?= $term->name; ?>">
                    <?php } ?>
                </ul>
                    </form>
```

Ajax

```
jQuery('li.blog-selection').each(function(){
jQuery(this).click(function() {
    var filter = jQuery(this);
    $.ajax({
        url:filter.attr('action'),
        data:filter.serialize(),
        type:filter.attr('method'),
        success:function(data){
            jQuery('.blog-wrapper__posts').html(data);
        }
    });
    //debugging
    //console.log(filter.attr('method'));
    return false;
})
});
```

WP_query

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
                'post_type' => 'blog',
                'posts_per_page' => 6,
                'paged' => $current_page_number,
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'blog_categories',
                        'terms' => $_POST['term'],
                        'field' => 'slug',
                    )
                ),
                ));
```

Comment: `this` in your code refers to the `li` element. It does not have the `action` or `method` attributes which you're trying to read. You need to get those from the `form` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not access the form for the filters.

I suggest you do this instead

```js
$('#tax-filter').on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  const $filter = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    url: $filter.attr('action'),
    data: $filter.serialize(),
    type: $filter.attr('method'),
    success: function(data) {
      $('.blog-wrapper__posts').html(data);
    }
  });
});

$('li.blog-selection').on("click", function() {
  $('#tax-filter').submit()
})
```

Comment: Now it returns post 400 error. And the value is 0

Comment: Look in the network tab to see if it is doing what you expect. You have not posted enough information to see if your script expects GET or POST and if the form works on its own